# Why Css specific borderstyles like ridge,groove,outset,inset doesn't work in javafx?

Tags: java, css, javafx, border

I am trying to get a 3d look by using groove,ridge border style in a JavaFX application.But it is showing me

```
Unsupported <border-style> 'groove' while parsing '-fx-border-style'
```

why JavaFX CSS has only limited border style like Dotted,dashed,solid.Besides, how can I achieve the 3d effect like the groove in javaFx borders?

Comment: put the error with code style is better to read, and please show your code which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems even JavaFX stated to follow CSS 2.1 `groove` and others [aren`t implemented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#pane).

Probably you can style with `-fx-border-image-source` or structural with a `Pane` in a `Pane`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 4;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
         <children>
            <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: gray; -fx-border-width: 4;" />
         </children>
</StackPane>
```